# Can I get my GF's cat to be comfortable with me after I scared it

Tags: cats

So my girlfriend has 2 cats right now. One she got several months ago and he's never had any issues with me. Recently she got a new kitten.

He was doing okay with me, but one night I was going to the restroom and didn't realize he had follow me, and because it was dark and he's black I didn't see him and accidentally stepped on him.

Since then, he's been very scared of me. He runs away every time I'm near him. The other day I was checking up on them for her as she's out of town, and he ran away from me but decided to try to run into his litter box and stumbled on his way in. He got poop smeared on him and I had to clean him.

He was making a lot of noise when I was cleaning him and afterwards the other cat also started hissing at me. Is there anyway to get them to be comfortable around me again? The newer cat always hisses and growls whenever I'm near him and I really want to get along with them.

Thanks!